# Toll-free bridging of CFError to NSError not working in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, core-foundation

Converting our codebase to Swift 3, I have this problem:

```
ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef) { (granted: Bool, error: CFError?) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            if let nsError = error as NSError {
                ...   
            }
        }
}
```

Compiler error is: 
`Cannot convert value of type 'CFError?' to type 'NSError' in coercion`

---

Changing to:

```
if let nsError = error as? NSError { ... }
```

Gives the warning: `Cast from 'CFError?' to unrelated type 'NSError' always fails`

Comment: Excuse me for pointing this out, but ABAddressBook is deprecated.

Comment: `if let nsError = error as Error? { ... }` should work, but I cannot test it currently, and as @matt said, that API is deprecated anyway.

Comment: @matt still supporting iOS 8

Comment: Yes, I was afraid of that. :(

Comment: @Ramsel I filed a bug for you: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3206

Comment: @matt thanks for filing

Answer (score 7):

Do not attempt to pass thru NSError at all. Coerce straight to Error, the Swift type.

```
if let err = error as? Error {
    print(err) // no problem
}
```

Comment: Minor remark: With `if let err = error as Error? {...}` the compiler will complain if `error` is not convertible to `Error?`.

Comment: @MartinR All I can tell you is that the above code compiles and runs correctly when the incoming `error` is an Optional CFError. That's the original problem so that's the problem I solved.

Comment: Yes, I did not doubt that.